# How to use data table in background in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I want to execute common steps for few test cases.below are the common steps.But in background,since i cannot use Scenario Outline,what is the alternate?

```
Background:To test employee id search 

Scenario Outline: 
Given I am on login Screen
When I enter credentials "<User_ID>" and "<Password>"
When I clicks on search button
And search by "<Employee_id>"

Examples:
|User_ID|Password  |Employee_id|
|Admin  |Password  | Q58ewQ    |
```

Comment: Background cannot be tied to Scenario Outline. Background works as a pre-condition steps to the other Scenarios and Scenario Outlines

Answer (score 0):

A scenario outline is a way to run several scenarios whilst writing just a single scenario. Background is a set of steps to run before each scenario. You can't put an outline in a background, it makes no sense.

Comment: Ya i know that we cant use selenium outline with Background.But just wanted to know  what is the alternative for this

Answer (score 0):

A [Background](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background) is used for steps that will be run before **each** Scenario (or Example) in the feature file.

Each [Scenario Outline](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline) will run as a separate [Scenario / Example](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#example).

You cannot use Scenario Outline **inside** a Background, as that would make no sense.

Please check the links to the documentation for more information.

Comment: In that case you would need to add the steps from Background to Scenario Outline, for each Scenario/Example

Answer (score 0):

This is example is very imperative, BDD need to be declarative. [Best Pratices BDD](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Best+Practice%3A+Imperative+v.+Declarative+Testing+Scenarios)

Why do you create one method that do login.

```
Login(username, password){
  set username = username;
  set password = password;
  clickButton;
}
```

And create one step.

```
Given the user logged on the system
  login(username, password)
```

This is step do you use with background.

Comment: Do you suggest me to include login credentials and other details in properties files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table in Cucumber `Background`:

```
Background:
    Given I open Google's search page
    When I use the following keywords to search in the Google's search page:
       | CucumberBDD    | 
       | CucumberHooks  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Data Table` in `Cucumber Background` :

```
Background:
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User Navigate to LogIn Page
    And User enters Credentials to LogIn
    | testuser_1 | Test@153 |
```